# Failed to serialize Alexa response com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletResponse using Gson

Tags: gson, alexa-skills-kit

I was trying to serialize a `com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletResponse` object using Gson, but it failed with the following exception:

```
*java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public com.amazon.speech.ui.OutputSpeech() with no args
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:113)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
```

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: null
at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:110)
... 98 common frames omitted*
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I am using com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5 and com.amazon.alexa:alexa-skills-kit:1.8.1

Comment: It does look like you're trying to deserialize instead of serializing, at least the traceback shows that  - note `fromJson` - and it does look like you're trying to deserialize `OutputSpeech` which is abstract and therefore can't be instantiated. Gson tries to instantiated the classes with reflection and in this case fails to find a suitable constructor. Can you confirm this somehow?

Comment: Fred, you are right, the problem is with deserializing SpeechletResponse. We looked at this object it does contains members like "OutputSpeech" which are abstract. Also, the implementation classes like "PlainTextOutputSpeech" doesn't have any non-arg constructor. I assume that is causing gson to fail, anyone knows an easy fix for this?  Is Amazon alexa planning to fix this ?

Comment: Honestly I don't know an easy fix for the abstract class. I can only think of custom deserializers that create concrete classes. As for classes with no-arg constructor should be fine as long as they can be instantiated. Deep down in gson's implementation, there's a part where it uses `Unsafe` which, if you're not familiar, let's just say it's a way to bypass the constructor. This is why gson can instantiate classes that have no-arg constructor. Ps: if you're not familiar with `Unsafe` I'd say it's a good thing, but would recommend on having a peek at it. It's a really nice read :)